# how to support line editing/history in C++ console program?

Tags: c++, console-application

I'm writing an interactive command-driven console program... think of something like Python, Matlab, etc. if that helps.  User types a command, gets a result, and repeats until done.

This works OK, but the only editing users can do is typing and Backspace.  I'd like to let them use standard line editing: arrow keys, ctrl-A/E, option-arrow to go by word, etc.  And (really asking a lot now), I'd also like them to be able to use up/down arrow to cycle through previous inputs, to edit/reenter those.

I'm aware of ncurses, but that seems like overkill; it's designed for making GUI-like interfaces, while what I want is a simple command-based interface.

I'm coding on a Mac, but I will soon want this to work on Linux and Windows too.  I'm willing to roll up my sleeves and do it myself if necessary, but surely there's something out there that either does this, or at least abstracts away the differences between Unix and Windows consoles, without dragging all of ncurses into the picture?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline

Comment: In Windows, if you get the input from `stdin` the previous inputs are available from the up/down arrow keys. It works the same way as the console command line, but it only presents the inputs that were taken by the program running.

Comment: https://github.com/troglobit/editline is a BSD-like licensed version.

Comment: @Weather Vane, that sounds like exactly the behavior I want — so I just need to pick or develop a solution to get the same behavior on the Unix/Linux.

Comment: Sounds like GNU Readline/editline is ideal — with editline possibly being preferable due to the license.  @Botje, if you want to post that as an answer I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: I just realized editline may not work on windows ‍♂️

Comment: Yeah, but according to @WeatherVane, Windows has this functionality built in.  So that turns out to be not an issue.